# gcc on my linux system is installed, still giving failure in installation

Tags: linux, unix, gcc, failed-installation

When I tried to install libxml2 on my linux server, it is giving me following error. Gcc on my machine is installed as well as fully updated, still it gives me error that your C compiler is not working, can anyone give me suggestion how to overcome it.

```
[root@localhost libxml2-2.8.0]# ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/root/tmpdir/libxml2-2.8.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: see config.log - what does it say?

Comment: it is giving long description- and showing that this many c files are not able to install due to unavailability of c compiler

Comment: does your shell needs to `rehash`? ie: what happens if you type `gcc -v` within *that* shell?

Comment: it is giving following details as:Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux

Comment: Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-mul

Comment: Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC)

Answer (score 0):

Just a few comments, not necessarily a solution... Do not use root for everyday usage (for me compiling libxml2 is an everyday situation). I would advise to create a "normal" user, and use it to work on your computer. `configure`, `make` with that user, and then `sudo make install`.

Then, depending on your Linux, I am almost sure there is a package for libxml2 and libxml2-devel. Try to install that, instead of manually compiling. This install by compile approach after some time tends to bring chaos to your computer...

Edit: To answer your comment:

- get the RPM: wget ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/x86_64/os/Packages/l/libxml2-2.9.1-2.fc20.x86_64.rpm

(up here be sure about your architecture, select the correct one, last column)

- install the RPM: [sudo] yum --nogpgcheck localinstall libxml2-2.9.1-2.fc20.x86_64.rpm

you might or might not need sudo... if you run this as root you will not need it.

Comment: i am not getting what you are saying? can you be more descriptive? i have libxml, i want to use libxml2

Comment: For libxml2 try: http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libxml2 ...since it seems to me you are on some redhat based machine.

Comment: i have tried that one, but how to install that library, i am getting problem in that installation, i m totally new user, please give me step by step solution, to install it, thank you for your support

Answer (score 0):

As in your output `C compiler cannot create executables`

Can you compile simple c file using gcc
in the configure file it checks the following

```
# Try to create an executable without -o first, disregard a.out.
# It will help us diagnose broken compilers, and finding out an intuition
# of exeext.
{ $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: checking whether the C compiler works" >&5
$as_echo_n "checking whether the C compiler works... " >&6; }
ac_link_default=`$as_echo "$ac_link" | sed 's/ -o *conftest[^ ]*//'

# The possible output files:
ac_files="a.out conftest.exe conftest a.exe a_out.exe b.out conftest.*"
```

does gcc without -o option provide executable file

Comment: it is giving me error as:[root@localhost ~]# gcc abc.c
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:385,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from abc.c:1:
/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:9:27: error: gnu/stubs-64.h: No such file or directory

Comment: but when i use command yum install gcc, it says that latest version of gcc is installed on your machine, what is actual problem, can you give me some suggesstion

Comment: can you try this
    yum groupinstall "Development tools"
since you're missing some header files
or just install this
    yum install glibc-headers

Comment: i have done group installation as well as glibc-headers install- but still after that getting the same error

Comment: are you using 64 bit system

Comment: system version:Linux version 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b18n3.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3) (GCC) )

Comment: you have to install glibc-headers.x86_64

Comment: yum install glibc-headers.x86-64 -this gives that no such package available- what to do next

Comment: glibc-headers-2.12-1.107.el6_4.5.x86_64 already installed if running  yum install glibc-headers

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40627/discussion-between-mdthakkar-and-vahid-abdi)

Comment: try this yum provides \*/gnu/stubs-64.h

Comment: still same issue continued... after installing that one

Comment: error: gnu/stubs-64.h: No such file or directory shows that you dont have gnu/stubs-64.h 
'yum provides */gnu/stubs-64.h' tell you which package provides 'gnu/stubs-64.h' file for you. if you still can't compile c file, check that gnu/stubs-64.h file exist using 'updatedb && locate gnu/stubs-64.h'